# Add a new rectangle(with min height to look like a line) between two components in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I want to draw a rectangle between the already existing two rectangles. I am unable to adjust the width and height of the rectangle which is to be added b/w two rectangles. Also I want to add actionListener on the newly added rectangles. What could be a better approach to addListenrer to newly drawn Rectangle? Precisely I want to know how to set the width and length of in the g2.draw().

[image]

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3f));

    int i = 0;
    int d = 0;
    for (TimeslotModel m: graph.model.slotModels) {
        TimeslotView v1 = m.getTimeslotView();
        for (TimeslotView v2: v1.connected) {
            int x1 = v1.getX();
            int y1 = v1.getY();
            int w1 = v1.getWidth();
            int h1 = v1.getHeight();
            int x2 = v2.getX();
            int y2 = v2.getY();
            int w2 = v2.getWidth();
            int h2 = v2.getHeight();
            //x2 = x2 + w2/2;
            //y2 = y2+ h2/2 ;
            //g2.drawRect(x1 + w1 / 2, y1 + h1 / 2 + d, x2 + w2/2, y2 + h2/2 + d);

            rect= new Rectangle(x1 + w1 / 2, y1 + h1 / 2 + d, x2 + w2/2 - 100, y2 + h2/2 + d);
            d += 4;

            g2.draw(rect);

            addMouseListener(new RightClickPopUpListener());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The image is the output of the code that I have added here

Comment: I want a thin rectangles b/w the components which can be seen in the picture.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) You've described a requirement or specification, but asked no question. What is your question? 3) The correct method for custom painting a `JComponent` is `paintComponent(Graphics)` 4) Don't add a listener in a paint method. 5) *"The image is the output of the code that I have added here"* That information should be in the question. Please [edit] to add it.

Comment: A painting method is for painting only. You should NOT be adding a MouseListener to your component.

Comment: rect= new Rectangle(x1 + w1 / 2, y1 + h1 / 2 + d, x2 + w2/2 - 100, y2 + h2/2 + d);
            d += 4;

            g2.draw(rect);

what values should I use for width and height to connect two rectangles,

Comment: *"what values should I use.."* Tip: Add @camickr (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. I'm closing this tab on the browser now, as it seems you are either unwilling or unable to implement the suggestions made earlier. Good luck with it.